# Recurrence relation: $T(n) = T(n-1) + 1/n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, self-learning

> \begin{align}
> T(0) & = 0 \\
> T(n) & = T(n-1) + \dfrac{1}{n}
> \end{align} solve the recurrence relation

My work so far:

\begin{align}
T(1) & = 1 \\
T(2) & = 1 + \dfrac{1}{2} \\
T(3) & = 1 + \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{3} \\
&\vdots
\end{align}

this is the harmonic series, which diverges.

What is the solution to the recurrence relation?

Comment: The actual recurrence relation is the first line of the question. If this is the whole problem, you’re probably expected to prove by induction that $T(n)=H_n$, the $n$-th [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), for $n\ge 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The harmonic series diverges when you take the sum to infinity, but this is just the sum to n, which can be calculated. What I'm basically saying is that I think the harmonic series is the right approach.